# Error on python nameERROR

Tags: python

Running the following

```
golfFile = open("golf.dat","a")
another = "Y"
while another=="Y":
    Name = input("What is the player's name?: ")
    Score = input("What is the player's score?: ")
    golfFile.write(Name+"\n")
    golfFile.write(Score+"\n")
    another = input("Do you wish to enter another player? (Y for yes): ")
    print()
golfFile.close()
print("Data saved to golf.dat")
```

Getting the following error
What is the player's name?: j

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nancy\Desktop\Calhoun\CIS\Chapter10#6A.py", line 4, in <module>
    Name = input("What is the player's name?: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.7, `input` tries to evaluate the input as a Python expression, while `raw_input` evaluates it as a string. Obviously, `j` is not a valid expression. Using `input` is in fact dangerous in some cases -- you don't want users to be able to execute arbitrary code in your application!

Thus, what you're looking for is `raw_input`.

Python 3 doesn't have `raw_input`, and the old `raw_input` has been renamed `input`. So, if you tried your code in Python 3, it would work.

```
golfFile = open("golf.dat","a")
another = "Y"
while another=="Y":
    Name = raw_input("What is the player's name?: ")
    Score = raw_input("What is the player's score?: ")
    golfFile.write(Name+"\n")
    golfFile.write(Score+"\n")
    another = raw_input("Do you wish to enter another player? (Y for yes): ")
    print()
golfFile.close()
print("Data saved to golf.dat")
```

Test:

```
>>> Name = input("What is the player's name?: ")
What is the player's name?: j
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
>>> Name = raw_input("What is the player's name?: ")
What is the player's name?: j
>>> Name
'j'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`:

```
Name = raw_input("What is the player's name?: ")
Score = raw_input("What is the player's score?: ")
```